# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent - Android

Tags: android

I am trying to open screen from system settings with intent from my app. So I have found the name of the activity in android settings and trying to launch it.

The address of the activity is
`com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings`

So with this code I'm trying to send an intent

```
val intent = Intent("com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings")
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        startActivity(intent)
```

But got this exception

```
            android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings flg=0x10000000 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
val intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.SubSettings"));
startActivity(intent);
```

There's always the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#constants) available for the Intent class and methods and constants. Also, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873268/17457752)